# wrong description being selected for Pinterest rich-pins

Tags: blogger, pinterest

I just recently requested Pinterest Rich-Pins on my blogsite which it approved.

However, the description it is providing is crazy long: it is selecting the entire contents of the articles rather than an abbreviation snippet.

> example >> http://pin.it/Ov1rvR4 <<

I have tried seeking answers direct with Pinterest CS but have received nothing but a default notice to check my original documentation - which I already did and cannot see where I am going wrong.

I would be extremely grateful for any insight you can offer to a solution on this. My only other course of action is to disable Rich-Pins which I am loathe to do for the affect it will have on my appearance in the Smart Feed algorithm.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, there is a problem in Pinterest share url. add your Blogger sharing buttons code.

Comment: thanks Bassam // blogger tries to be clever and switches the [dot]com for a country code if you are accessing the site from another location, this does play havoc with it // however if you manually code the pin to [dot]com then it tries to apply the rich-pin feature // since posting this I do seem to have found a potential solution that is more than Pinterest instructions // you can see that here >> http://www.digitalkonline.com/blog/add-rich-pins-blogger/ <<